# Storing session variables not working

Tags: c#

[image]Ok, back in the day, I used to store session variables as such:

```
 Session["NAME"] = Value;
```

However, doing this in 4.5 doesn't seem to work. When I debug, and check the value of Session, using QuickWatch in visual studio 2012 - I get the following:

```
NAME = DUP (this is my session name)
VALUE = The Name 'DUP' does not exist in the current context.
```

So, I thought perhaps, I dont instantiate from Page, in the class - but I do. So I tried using
     `HTTPContext.Current.Session`

But Current isn't showing in visual studio as a valid option.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're doing in quickwatch?

Comment: May be this is a problem with scope. This sometimes happens with the visual studio 2012. But we cannot provide any solution unless you provide some screen shots.

Comment: Try `HttpContext.Current.Session` (casing) and make sure you reference System.Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot suggests that you have selected incorrect variable name. It should be Session["DUP"] or something like that, not AML.

Comment: this is just another example of the same problem, the other page with DUP has been checked out by another developer

Comment: All i'm trying to do is create a session variable called AML and assign it a value

Comment: @JakubKonecki: AML is an undeclared variable in the current context. Session works like a dictionary/hashtable, and to access a particular element, you need to use its indexer like Session["AML"]

Comment: @dotNET - Ah, you mean in QuickWatch window... ;-) You might want to clarify your answer, it's not obvious...

Comment: i'm not doing anything different to what is on this site:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6ad7zeeb(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @WayneAtherton: You may be correct. It may just be that you have posted incorrect screenshot. Notice that you're checking a variable in QuickWatch window that does not exist. Try Session["AML"] or Session["DUP"] instead.

Comment: Ok, there was something strange with my environemnt, i rebooted the machine, and it's sorted itself out. Thanks for the minus :-(

Comment: @WayneAtherton: Glad u figured it out. That minus was not from me though, just to keep records straight. :)